# Magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3 post upgrade errors while adding to cart

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.3

> After upgrading from 2.3.5 to 2.4.3 in local setup, while adding to cart shows an
> error as shown in the below screenshot

https://nimb.ws/rhTCgf

**There are some third-party modules that I tried disabling but then the site couldn't able to load. There are no logs generating in the `var/logs` folder**

Please let me know if you have any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow found a solution.

**There was a custom module which was causing this issue specifically below code,**

```
 // \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $this->httpContext
 $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
```

So used this class `Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` instead of `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context`

**Hope this helps.**